A question about the definition of derivative in different coordinate systems
The definition of the derivative goes like this: If $x$ is an interior point of a set $E \subseteq {\Bbb R}^n$, then a function $f: {\Bbb R}^n \rightarrow {\Bbb R}^m$ is said to be differentiable at $x$ if there is a linear mapping $L: T{\Bbb R}^n_a \rightarrow T{\Bbb R}^m_{f(a)}$, s.t.
$f(x+h) - f(x) = L(h) + \alpha(x;h)$,
where $h \in T{\Bbb R}^n_a$ and $\alpha(x;h) = o(h)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$.
Now I don’t seem to understand fully this last bit. $\alpha(x;h) = o(h)$ means that $\|\alpha(x;h)\|_{{\Bbb R}^m} = o(\|h\|_{{\Bbb R}^n})$. If the position of the point $x$ is given by Cartesian coordinates as, say, $(x_1, x_2)$, then the norm of the displacement vector $h$ is given simply by the Pythagorean theorem. What if instead we describe the point $x$ by polar coordinates $(r, \theta)$? What definition of the norm of the displacement vector $h=(\delta r, \delta \theta)$ to use then? Is it just $\delta r$ or $\sqrt{(\delta r)^2 + (\delta \theta)^2}$? Further, how do you define a norm when you deal with, for example, thermodynamics, where state points are described by 3 variables $(P, V, T)$, when, for example, the formula $\sqrt{P^2+V^2+T^2}$ does not make any sence physically?

It doesn't really matter because all reasonable choices are equivalent (in the sense that the same functions are differentiable with the same derivatives).
